# is the operator '+' unary or binary?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

While reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f672kxz8.aspx) article it seems that the operator + is unary. How is that.
From my understanding a unary operator is an operator that does not depend on another variable for its operation like ++a or a-- . How is the variable '+' unary. I thought it was binary ? I would appreciate it if some one could clear this up.

Comment: There's a unary plus (`+x`) and a binary plus (`a + b`). He must be referring to only one.

Comment: By unary, they mean that it can be used for indicating the sign . As in `(-) for negative` and `(+) for positive`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`+` is both a unary and binary operator.  The unary `+` form (`+a`) forces the operand to be evaluated as a number or a pointer, while the binary form `+` form (`a + b`) is addition.

Unary `+` is generally the opposite of unary `-`; applying it to any numeric value will not change it. (`+1 == 1`) However, it does have some uses, including forcing an array to decay into a pointer:

```
template <typename T> void foo(const T &) { }

void test() {
    int a[10];

    foo(a);  // Calls foo<int[10]>()
    foo(+a); // Calls foo<int*>()
}
```

([Demo](http://ideone.com/95AG97))

It's the same deal with the `-` and `*` operators. You have `-a` (negation) and `a - b` (subtraction); `*a` (pointer dereference) and `a * b` (multiplication).

You overload both versions differently.  For overloading via member functions:

```
public:
    T operator+() const;          // Unary
    T operator+(const U &) const; // Binary
```

As with any other operator overload, both forms can return a value different from their enclosing type; for example you might have a string class whose `operator+()` returns a numeric type.  This would be in line with the convention of unary `+` evaluating its operand as a number.

You can overload these operators as free functions, too:

```
T operator+(const U &);            // Unary, called on type U and returns T.
T operator+(const U &, const V &); // Binary, called on types U and V and returns T.
```

Comment: Marked as answer. Thanks

Comment: I think for a C++ question you should give an example how to overload the unary and binary plus operator.

Comment: @Kay I will add that now.

Answer (score 1):

Unary +  as in +a is defined to complement unary - (-a). It is the "default" so actually not often if ever used. However it can be used with variables refering to classes, where it can be overloaded to have a class-specific meaning. So it is not quite entirely useless.