# What does "int* p=+s;" do?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, unary-operator

I saw a weird type of program [here](https://ideone.com/UbvCp5).

```
int main()
{
    int s[]={3,6,9,12,18};
    int* p=+s;
}
```

Above program tested on **GCC** and **Clang** compilers and working fine on both compilers.

I curious to know, What does `int* p=+s;` do?

Is array `s` decayed to pointer type?

Comment: That is exactly the purpose. This truck is also if you want to decay a lambda to a function pointer

Comment: Plus before `s` can be safely omitted, it has no effect

Comment: s is pointer to int, there is no such thing as "array type" in C.

Comment: There is array type in C. Try for example `sizeof` an array and a pointer.

Comment: @ziza [arrays are completely different from pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1641957/995714). For example if we have `int b[2]; int a* = b;` then `int *c = b+1` and `int *d = a + 1` will contain different values

Comment: I would use `int* p = &s[0]`. But that's me. Actually, I would use `std::array`...

Comment: And please, if you're going to write code like this, at least write it "int* p = +s" (with spaces around the '='), to make it clear that this was intended to be a unary '+', unless you're trying to confuse anyone who has to maintain this code...

Comment: So you determine array size by using sizeof, but this is compile time operator and it works with statically allocated array. It is also possible to dinamically create array, what would be result of sizeof then?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: [No they don't...?!?](https://ideone.com/uvo2CS) I agree arrays and pointers are different things, but your example is wrong.

Comment: It may be of anecdotal interest that [the `+=` operator originally was `=+`,](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/3e/docs/chistory.html) which was changed presumably exactly because of the ambiguity with the unary `+`.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc @DevSolar is right. in `b+1` `b` decays to a pointer to its first element, i.e. is equal in type and value to `a`. If you want to point out (heh) the esistence of real arrays you could do something like `int *p = b; int  (*pa)[2] = &b; cout << "p: " << p << "pa: " << pa << "p+1: " << p+1 << "pa+1: " << pa+1 << endl;` which should yield equal values for `p` and `pa` but different ones for the respective increments (because `pa` would point to the next *array* if there were one).

Comment: @ziza No, that is not possible. A pointer is a pointer. The area pointed to is generally unknown.

Comment: @ziza: You cannot apply `sizeof` to a dynamically allocated array because dynamically allocated array does not have a name. Also, this question is about C++, not about C. In C unary `+` is not applicable in this fashion, which would prevent the code from compiling. The question is exclusively about C++.

Comment: @SeanBurton If you're going to write code like this then put `int* p = std::decay(s);`

Comment: @M.M you meant `std::decay_t<int>()`?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Built-in [`operator+`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Unary_arithmetic_operators) could take pointer type as its operand, so passing the array `s` to it causes [array-to-pointer conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Array_to_pointer_conversion) and then the pointer `int*` is returned. That means you might use `+s` individually to get the pointer. (For this case it's superfluous; without `operator+` it'll also decay to pointer and then assigned to `p`.)

(emphasis mine)

> The built-in unary plus operator returns the value of its operand. The only situation where it is not a no-op is when the operand has integral type or unscoped enumeration type, which is changed by integral promotion, e.g, it converts char to int or if the operand is subject to lvalue-to-rvalue, **array-to-pointer**, or function-to-pointer conversion.

Comment: Is it valid in C as well?

Comment: @machine_1 Sorry I don't know. I'm not familiar with C, they're different language. :)

Comment: @machine_1 Not really. In C, the unary + operator converts `char` to `int` like in C++, but putting it before an array, a pointer, or a function isn't valid in C.

Comment: @DonaldDuck: I think you mean putting it before pointer-type values, including array and functions *that decompose into such values and don't dereference the resulting pointer*.  Given `double arr[20], someFunc(void), x;` code could perfectly legitimately do `x= +arr[5];` or `x = +someFunc();` since the array and function are dereferenced.

Answer (score 25):

Test this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    char s[] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o' , ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd', '!'} ;
    printf("sizeof(s) : %zu,  sizeof(+s) : %zu\n", sizeof(s), sizeof(+s) ) ;
}
```

On my PC (Ubuntu x86-64) it prints:

```
sizeof(s): 12,  sizeof(+s) : 8
```

where

```
12 = number of elements s times size of char, or size of whole array
 8 = size of pointer
```

Comment: `char s[] = "Hello worl";` [sic!] would have been more readable.

Comment: `"Hello worl!"` would have an implicit `'\0'` at the end

Answer (score 11):

That's a unary plus symbol which has no practical effect here. For example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int a[] = {1};

    std::cout << a << " " << +a << std::endl;
}
```

This prints the same address for both `a` and `+a`. The array is decayed to pointer as usual.

Note that, if it had been an unary minus `-a` instead then GCC would show the error:

```
error: wrong type argument to unary minus
```

Edit: Though it has no effect in OP's code, `a` and `+a` are not exactly same. Please refer to the answers by Khurshid Normuradov and songyuanyao for details.

Comment: your answer is in constrast to most others by saying that "a unary plus symbol which has no practical effect here". However, `std::cout << a;` only prints the same because `operator<<` triggers the decay to a pointer as well, but still `a` is an array while `+a` is a pointer to the first element

Comment: hm I think your answer is correct insofar as in OPs code the `+` really has no practical effect, because (if i am not mistaken) already the `=` makes the array decay. Nevertheless your answer can be mistunderstood as `a` being the same as `+a`.

Comment: @user463035818 you are right. Other two answers cover that better than mine. So edited the answer a little bit to avoid such confusion.

Answer (score 10):

> Is array `s` decayed to pointer type?

**Yes.**

> What does `int* p=+s;` do?

Unary `+` operator forces the array to decay to a pointer.

**C++ Standard, 5.3.1 Unary operators(P7):**

> The operand of the unary + operator shall have arithmetic, unscoped
>   enumeration, or **pointer type** and the result is the value of the
>   argument. Integral promotion is performed on integral or enumeration
>   operands. The type of the result is the type of the promoted operand.

The unary `+` form `(+s)` forces the operand to be evaluated as a number or a pointer.

For more information, please see this [stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26823537/6935629).

Answer (score 0):

Here unary **+** is just making *p to point the addresses of Integer array.
Let's take two array s1 and s2

```
int s1[]={1,5,2};
int s2[]={2,5,2};

int *p=+s1;
p=+s2; 
printf("%d",(int)p[0]);
```

Output: 2

So in my point of view unary + is just making pointer p to point the array s 
beginning address.